# Storing expanding data of weeks

Tags: mysql

i've tried searching for this but since i dont know what its actually called i have no idea if i even got the correct results. anyhow:

lets say that i have this data:

week 43, 44,47,49,50,51 <- year 2011.
week 01, 02,09,12,16,22 <- year 2012

this data just keeps expanding over the years, but i wanna save everything from the starting point. how would you store this in a mysql db? do you just have a column named week and make the data like this?:

4311,4411,4711,4911,5011,5111,0112,0212,0912,1612,2212? or is there a better way of storing data like this? i hope i wasnt too vague

Answer (score 0):

One possible way is to have a year table, a week table (with weeks from 1 to 52) and a table connecting both (like weeks_in_year) where you keep the id of both the year and the week.

Another, quicker way, is to have just one table with two columns: week and year, and just search by the year field when you need to get the weeks..